# problem with uiimageView animation

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, uiimageview, allocation

here is my code :

```
-(void) createNewImage {
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boutonplay_03.png"];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

[imageView setCenter:[self randomPointSquare]];
[[self view] addSubview:imageView];
ix=imageView.center.x;
iy=imageView.center.y;

X=(240-ix)/230;
Y=(160-iy)/230;
```

}

```
-(void)Animation{

imageView.center = CGPointMake(imageView.center.x + X, imageView.center.y + Y);
```

}

"CreateNewImage" is alled every 2 seconds, and there is a CADisplayLink on "Animation".

My problem is that the animation of  "imageView" stops every 2 seconds because a new "imageView" is created and this last start moving and it stops again after 2 seconds, and again and again and again ... What I would like is to make "imageView" continue his animation in spite of the creation of new "imageView".How can I do this please ? sorry for my english I'm french:/

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if imageView == nil or not.

```
if (imageView == nil) {
 imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
}
//rest of code
```

Comment: with your code there is a problem: the imageView is animated but after some seconds it disappear and another image imageView is created and it is animated and so on...

Comment: I implemented it and there is a problem, my comment is the problem

Comment: Your comment doesn't make sense. You have summed up your problem in a sentence and does not actually outline any other problem that you seem to be receiving.

Comment: yes but I don't know why you wrote" if (imageView == nil)" I don't really understiand

Comment: because you don't need to re-instantiate a non nil variable. This is what is causing the whole problem. If you don't declare imageView again and again, there won't be an error.

Comment: so if it works , try to implement it with my code and you'll see what is the problem

Comment: No, because I know that this code works. Why don't YOU try it?

Comment: I try it but my problem is my first comment I don't know how to explain it another way, it is exactly what happen

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new UIImageView every time you call CreateNewImage

instead, check to see if it has already been created.

```
-(void) createNewImage {
if(imageView == nil) {
     UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boutonplay_03.png"];
     imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
}

[imageView setCenter:[self randomPointSquare]];
[[self view] addSubview:imageView];
ix=imageView.center.x;
iy=imageView.center.y;

X=(240-ix)/230;
Y=(160-iy)/230;

}
```

Comment: with your code there is a problem: the imageView is animated but after some seconds it disappear and another image imageView is created and it is animated and so on

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your case, what happens is this:

1. you create a new image in `createNewImage`;
2. this image is animated through the method:

   ```
   -(void)Animation{
      imageView.center = CGPointMake(imageView.center.x + X, imageView.center.y + Y);
   }
   ```

   which animates your `imageView` ivar;
3. when you create a new image, after 2 seconds, you reassign it to the `imageView` ivar, so that the `Animation` method can animate it when it is called;
4. at the same time, you have lost the reference to your previous image that you were animating before, so Animation will not animate it anymore.

Now what I suggest is trying to change `Animation` in this way:

```
    -(void)Animation{
       for (UIView* imgView in self.view.subviews) {
            imgView.center = CGPointMake(imgView.center.x + X, imgView.center.y + Y);
       }
    }
```

So, this will simply animate *any* subview of your main view. If your only subviews are the images you want to animate, it should be fine.

EDIT:

From your description in the comments, it seems to me that what happens is that `addSubview` has the effect of stopping shortly all animations. I don't know if this is related to loading the images from disk, but I remember I also experienced a similar problem time ago. The only approach I see is pre-creating and pre-adding all the UIImageViews you need (or a maximum number of allowed images), make them all hidden and then making them visible again one by one. This would make the logic of your program more complex, but it would work.

Another approach could be using `CALayer`s instead of `UIVIew`s. Best thing would be using a CABasicAnimation to animate your images.

If you want to use UIImageView, you could get `[imageView layer]` and add this one instead of the view, like this:

```
[[self.view layer] addSublayer:[imageView layer]];
```

but I am not sure that this approach would work.

Hope that his helps.

Comment: with your code there is another problem imageView is animated but always go and get stuck to the new position of new imageView

Comment: I try it and the problem is my previous coment

Comment: Strange, because  we are now moving the `imgView.center`, and it should not have anything to do with the new position of the last `imageView` you create...

Comment: the thing that happen is very strange imageView is created and it move and then it stops and another imageView is created and move and the two images move to the same direction and so on ...

Comment: I saw it : Your first suggestion is not possible due to the memory, the second i don't really understand it because I never use Layers and then the CABasicAnimation is not possible because I use CGRectIntersect and with CABasicAnimation it is not possible so I don't know what should I do